# Reset angular table binded with NgRepeat

Tags: html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that I'm binding with and NG repeat. I have an add button that will add more rows to this table when necessary. I also have and save/Cancel button to save the changes done into that table or to revert the added rows. How do I remove the rows added to this table when I click cancel so I show the initial state of the page?.

To add a new row what I'm doing is:

```
$(".socialMediaContainer tbody").append("<tr><td><input name=\"hdnsocialID\" class=\"hdnSocialID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"0\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtSocialName\" class=\"txtLabel socialName\" placeholder=\"Name\" maxlength=\"250\" value=\"\"/></td><td><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtSocialURL\" class=\"txtLabel socialURL\" placeholder=\"URL\" maxlength=\"250\" value=\"\"/></td><td class='DragnDropIcon'></td><td><a class=\"button orange wImg\">Upload <input id='fileSocialUpload" + controlId + "' name='fileSocialUpload" + controlId + "' type=\"file\" class=\"file\" onchange= \"aztec.bc.BrandController.UploadSocialPreViewImage(this,'" + id + "');\"  /></a></td><td><img class=\"socialMedia-container socialImg" + controlId + "\" src='/resources/Images/35x35.png' id=\"fileSocialUpload\"</td>" + socialbuttons + "</tr>");
```

Comment: reset the length of the array that is holding the rows? It's hard to answer your question without some sort of code showing what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a copy of the data you're binding to the `ng-repeat` and save to a variable (i.e. `originalData`).  Then, if the user clicks Cancel, just throw away the data they've edited and set data back to `originalData`.

```
var i;
var originalData = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
   originalData.push(angular.copy(data[i]));
}
```

Then your `ng-repeat` looks at 'data':

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">...</div>
```

If the user cancels, then just set data back:

```
if (cancel) {
   data = originalData;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I'm not adding the new rows in the array that the ngrepeat is using. I;m adding the row directly by modifying the html

Comment: How so?  Can you post your HTML in the original question?

Comment: @GiovanniRivas adding the row by modifiying the HTML in AngularJS is WRONG ! Your are not using the benifits of AngularJs databinding & undesirable sideeffects !

Comment: @aorfevre I'm new to angular and i don't know all the good of it, can you guide me of how can I do it?

Comment: You don't need jQuery here.  If you add a new row to the data array you're binding to ng-repeat, it will be automatically reflected in your view

Comment: @GiovanniRivas : http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=course&gclid=Cj0KEQjwvuuqBRDG95yR6tmfg9oBEiQAjE3RQOyJUI30dFhl3LTLMtquV8auM9PWpuS59LhQDwJUQqAaAnpR8P8HAQ